# Wiring light switch with 9 wires

Tags: wiring, switch

I am trying to install a single pole rocker switch in a bedroom. It has 3 sets of wires coming out. One each with a black, white and copper ground. I put all 3 black on the top pole, all 3 white on the bottom pole and all 3 copper on the ground screw. When I turn the switch off the breaker kicks. Any ideas?

Comment: you are shorting all of the black wires to all of the white wires when you turn on the switch .... just connect it same as the old switch

Comment: What do I do?  The switch I replaced is different than the old one. Both single pole but the old one was a trailer switch that you push the wires in. I thought you would put all 3 together but on the different screws??

Comment: Bet you didn't take pictures of how it was wired, either, eh? Fun times ahead.

Comment: Since the old switch was definitely not wired that way, why would you think that.  Busting into the neutral bundle when the old switch never connected to it, was just dumb.  If you don't know, find out, don't experiment with electrical.

Answer (score 4):

The blacks are *hot* and *switched hot*. The whites are all *neutral*. Put them together on the switch and turn it on and the breaker *should* trip.

**In the future, before disconnecting the old switch or receptacle, take a picture and mark the wires as you disconnect them. Don't disconnect/move/unbundle any wires not connected to the old switch or receptacle.** *

* Exception: If the old switch didn't need neutral and the new switch needs neutral then you need to tap into the neutral bundle, if there is one.

---

You most likely have 3 cables with different purposes:

- Incoming Power
- Light Fixture
- Outgoing Power to the *next* switch or receptacle

Figuring out which is which is the tricky part. To do this properly, you need some tools. Ideally a [Non-Contact Voltage Tester](https://amzn.to/3zxFeA3), a [Multimeter](https://amzn.to/3QhaZTX), some wire nuts and colored electrical tape (typically a pack of black/white/red/yellow/blue). All of which should be UL or ETL listed for safety.

- Connect the white wires together with a wire nut. They will stay that way.
- Connect the ground wires together with a wire nut, with a short pigtail (bare or green wire) to the switch ground screw.
- Separate the black wires. Put a wire nut on each one for safety.
- Turn on the breaker. Use the NCVT to determine which black wire is **incoming hot**. *If more than one shows hot, testing with a multimeter may be needed.*
- Turn off the breaker. Connect the incoming hot to one screw of the switch.
- Connect one of the other black wires to the other screw of the switch. This will be **switched hot**.
- Turn on the breaker. See if the switch works to turn the light on/off. If it does, mark the switched hot wire with a piece of red tape. Connect the third black wire, **outgoing hot**, to the black incoming hot wire.
- If the switch has no effect then the third black wire is the switched hot. Turn off the breaker. Swap it with the second wire on the switch. Turn on and test. If it works, mark it with red tape and connect the other wire to the black hot wire.

Note that you can't necessarily connect two wires to a switch screw. But what you can always do is add a pigtail, a short piece of black wire (12 AWG for a 20A circuit, 12 AWG or 14 AWG for a 15A circuit) to the two wires (incoming hot and outgoing hot) and connect the pigtail to the switch screw.

Comment: Thank you!! That’s turned out to be the issue. The 3 white actually went together on a wire nut and didn’t hook to switch at all. The 3 black hooked to the switch and the ground. Thank you!!

Comment: @Chris the black wire should not connect to ground